# state becomes undefined after async call

Tags: reactjs, express

Trying to understand why the component's state is becoming undefined. 
 Before the async call the console shows this.state.pubsubtopics as [], after the call it becomes undefined

code:

```
class PubSubTopics extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pubsubtopics: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('after component mounted');
        console.log(this.state.pubsubtopics);
        this.callBackEndAPI()
            .then(res =>
                this.setState({pubsubtopics: res.express}))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        console.log('after setting state');
        console.log(this.state.pubsubtopics);
    }

    callBackEndAPI = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/listtopics');
        const body = await response.json();

        if(response.status !== 200){
            throw Error(body.message)
        }
        return body;
    }

    handlePrintStateClick = () => {
        console.log(this.state.pubsubtopics);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                </ul>
                <button onClick={this.handlePrintStateClick}>printState</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Logs (last log entry is from clicking the button):

```
after component mounted
index.js:16 []
index.js:21 after setting state
index.js:22 []
index.js:36 undefined
```

Comment: You might want to ensure your response is actually being returned correctly as you assign it like this: ```this.setState({pubsubtopics: res.express}))```. This will most likely be the line in trouble

Comment: can you make sure that res.express is actually the a value that is defined in response

Comment: Besides what others said, setState is async so to make sure some code gets executed afterwards hand it a callback as second parameter.

Comment: Thanks, all of you were correct, I should have been using res.topics since 'express' didn't exist in the response.  xDreamCoding - I don't understand what you mean by handing it a callback, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

res.express didn't exist in the server's response, using res.topics solved the problem